# h2o server fails when I start a grid search

Tags: h2o

I'm doing a grid search on a classification model.  When the h20 server starts I get:

```
R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         9 minutes 35 seconds 
    H2O cluster version:        3.10.4.8 
    H2O cluster version age:    14 days, 4 hours and 1 minute  
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_Charles_huu844 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   21.31 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    8 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  8 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    R Version:                  R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
```

When my model enters the grid search, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 412 Precondition Failed (url = http://localhost:54321/99/Grids/mygrid?sort_by=auc&decreasing=TRUE)

water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException
 [1] "water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument for sort_by specified. Must be one of: [r2, mean_per_class_accuracy, max_per_class_error, err, total_rows, rmse, accuracy, err_count, logloss, mse, mean_per_class_error]"
 [2] "    hex.schemas.GridSchemaV99.fillFromImpl(GridSchemaV99.java:114)"
```

My R script is as follows:

```
rm(list=ls())
options(scipen=999) # remove E notation
ptm <- proc.time()

if (Sys.info()["sysname"] == "Windows") {
  filePath = "//bigsur/sm/Trending/model.csv"
  homedir = "c:/sm/Trending/"
  setwd("c:/sm/Trending/R")
  sink("C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/log.txt")
} else {
  filePath = "/Volumes/sm/Trending/model.csv"
  homedir = "/Volumes/sm/Trending/"
  setwd("/Volumes/sm/Trending/R")
  sink("~/Desktop/log.txt")
}

#install.packages("ggplot2")
#install.packages("dplyr")

sink.reset <- function(){
  for(i in seq_len(sink.number())){
    sink(NULL)
  }
}

printf <- function(...) print(sprintf(...))

results = function(title, best_model) {
  best_params = best_model@parameters
  best_activation            <<- best_model@parameters$activation
  best_hidden                <<- best_model@parameters$hidden
  best_l1                    <<- best_model@parameters$l1
  best_l2                    <<- best_model@parameters$l2
  best_input_dropout_ratio   <<- best_model@parameters$input_dropout_ratio
  best_hidden_dropout_ratios <<- best_model@parameters$hidden_dropout_ratios

  printf(" ")
  printf("%s", title)
  best_model
  plot(best_model)
  h2o.performance(best_model)
  h2o.performance(best_model, valid = TRUE)
  h2o.mse(best_model, valid = TRUE)

  printf("mse: %f", best_model@model$validation_metrics@metrics$MSE)
  printf("best activation: %s", best_activation)
  cat("best hidden layers: ", best_hidden, "\n")
  printf("Best l1: %f", best_l1)
  printf("Best l2: %f", best_l2)
  #printf("best_input_dropout_ratio: %f", best_input_dropout_ratio)
  #cat("Best best_hidden_dropout_ratios: ", best_hidden_dropout_ratios, "\n")

  predictions = h2o.predict(best_model, test)
  summary(predictions, exact_quantiles=TRUE)
  predicted = predictions[,1]
  test_targets = test[, 5]
  correct = predicted == test_targets
  numCorrect = as.integer(sum(correct))
  ntotal = as.integer(nrow(correct))
  percent = round(numCorrect/ntotal*100, 2)
  printf("Correct classifications on all data: %d/%d (%f)", numCorrect, ntotal, percent)

  #predicted.h2o = h2o.assign(predicted, key = "predicted.h2o")
  #correct.h2o = h2o.assign(correct, key = "correct.h2o")

  perf_test = h2o.performance(model = best_model, newdata = test)
  cat("\nPerformance on test dataset\n")
  print(perf_test)
  cat("\nConfusion matrix on test dataset\n")
  h2o.confusionMatrix(perf_test)

  # Plot Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) curve and find its Area Under the Curve (AUC)
  # A ROC curve is a graph of the true positive rate (recall) against the false positive
  # rate for a binary classifier.
  #plot(f1_best_model, type = "cutoffs", col = "blue")

  cm = h2o.confusionMatrix(best_model, train)
  print("Confusion Matrix: ")
  print(cm)
  true_negative = cm[1,1]
  true_positive = cm[2,2]
  false_negative = cm[2,1]
  false_positive = cm[1,2]
  total = true_negative + true_positive + false_negative + false_positive
  accuracy = (true_positive + true_negative)/total
  printf("accuracy: %f", accuracy)

  misclassification_rate = (false_positive + false_negative)/total
  printf("misclassification_rate: %f", misclassification_rate)

  cat("\nVariable importance\n")
  print(best_model@model$variable_importance)

  return_list = c(best_activation,
                  best_hidden,
                  best_l1,
                  best_l2,
                  best_input_dropout_ratio,
                  best_hidden_dropout_ratios)

  return (return_list)
}

library(h2o)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

localH2O = h2o.init(ip = "localhost",
                    port = 54321,
                    startH2O = TRUE,
                    max_mem_size="24G",
                    nthreads = -1)
h2o.no_progress()
h2o.removeAll() ## clean slate - just in case the cluster was already running


print(filePath)
model.full <- read.csv(filePath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
head(model.full)
remove = !colnames(model.full) %in% c("Date",
                                      "Symbol",
                                      "BuyIndex",
                                      "SellIndex",
                                      "BoxRatio",
                                      "Acceleration",
                                      "nPosVelo",
                                      "Gain")
model_orig = model.full[, remove]
head(model_orig)
model = model_orig[sample(nrow(model_orig)),] # shuffle the rows
head(model)

df <- as.h2o(model, destination_frame = "df")

splits <- h2o.splitFrame(df, c(0.6,0.2), seed=1234)
train  <- h2o.assign(splits[[1]], "train.hex") # 60%
valid  <- h2o.assign(splits[[2]], "valid.hex") # 20%
test   <- h2o.assign(splits[[3]], "test.hex")  # 20%

printf("train----------------------------------------")
head(train)
train
printf("valid----------------------------------------")
#head(valid)
valid
printf("test-----------------------------------------")
#head(test)
test

p1 = train$Thrust
p2 = train$Velocity
p3 = train$OnBalRun
p4 = train$vwapGain
p1d = rbind(lapply(p1, as.double))  # p1 is an environment variable, we need doubles
p2d = rbind(lapply(p2, as.double))
p3d = rbind(lapply(p3, as.double))
p4d = rbind(lapply(p4, as.double))
a = unlist(p1d)
b = unlist(p2d)
c = unlist(p3d)
d = unlist(p4d)

pairs(train[1:4], main = "Scatterplot of predictors", pch = 21, cex = 0.8, bg = c("green3", "red")[unclass(model$Altitude)])

cat("\n\n1. Summary of train dataset------------------------------------------------------\n")
summary(train, exact_quantiles=TRUE)

cat("\n\n2. Grid Search on valid data ----------------------------------------------------\n")

activation_opts = c("RectifierWithDropout","TanhWithDropout","MaxoutWithDropout")
hidden_opts = list(c(80),c(100),c(200),c(300),c(400),c(500),
                   c(80,80),c(100,100),c(200,200),c(300,300),c(400,400),c(500,500),
                   c(80,80,80,80),c(100,100,100,100),c(200,200,200,200),c(300,300,300,300),
                   c(80,80,80,80,80),c(100,100,100,100,100),c(200,200,200,200,200),
                   c(300,300,300,300,300),c(400,400,400,400,400),c(500,500,500,500,500),
                   c(80,80,80,80,80,80),c(100,100,100,100,100,100),c(200,200,200,200,200,200),
                   c(300,300,300,300,300,300),c(400,400,400,400,400,400),
                   c(500,500,500,500,500,500)
                   )
l1_opts = runif(1, 0, 0.0001)
l2_opts = runif(1, 0, 0.0001)

hyperparams = list(
  activation = activation_opts,
  hidden = hidden_opts,
  l1 = l1_opts,
  l2 = l2_opts,
  max_w2 = 10
)

search_criteria = list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete",
                       stopping_metric = "misclassification",
                       max_models = 10000,
                       max_runtime_secs = 72000,
                       stopping_tolerance = 0.00001,
                       stopping_rounds = 10)

grid_model = h2o.grid(algorithm = "deeplearning",
                      grid_id = "mygrid",
                      hyper_params = hyperparams,
                      search_criteria = search_criteria,
                      x = 1:4,
                      y = 5,
                      training_frame = train,
                      validation_frame = valid,
                      variable_importances = TRUE,
                      balance_classes=TRUE,
                      score_training_samples=1000,
                      score_validation_samples=1000,
                      score_validation_sampling="Stratified",
                      epochs = 1000000,
                      seed = 7)

cat("\n\n3. Summary of grid_model---------------------------------------------------------\n")
grid = h2o.getGrid("mygrid", sort_by="auc", decreasing=TRUE)
summary(grid)

cat("\n\n4. Performance of best_model-----------------------------------------------------\n")
best_model = h2o.getModel(grid@model_ids[[1]])

results("5.best_model", best_model)

cat("\n\n6. Performance valid dataset-----------------------------------------------------\n")
perf_valid = h2o.performance(model = best_model, newdata = valid)
perf_valid

cat("\n\n7. Performance on test dataset---------------------------------------------------\n")
perf_test = h2o.performance(model = best_model, newdata = test)
perf_test

plot(perf_test, type="roc")     # Plot the roc curve

predicted <- h2o.predict( best_model, test )
actual = test[,5]
cat("\n\n8. Mean prediction on the test set: ", 100*mean( predicted$predict == actual ), "%\n")
correct = predicted == actual
numCorrect = as.integer(sum(correct))
ntotal = as.integer(nrow(correct))
percent = round(numCorrect/ntotal*100, 2)
printf("9. Test of Mean prediction on the test set: %d/%d (%f)", numCorrect, ntotal, percent)
cat("\n\n10. The 'test' set auc is: ", h2o.auc(perf_test), "\n")

p = h2o.saveModel(best_model, path = "C:\\sm\\Trending\\h2o_model", force = TRUE)
p

minutes = (proc.time() - ptm)[1]
printf("Elapsed time: %.2f minutes", minutes)

unlink("log.txt")
sink.reset()
```

My log is:

```
 Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         9 minutes 35 seconds 
    H2O cluster version:        3.10.4.8 
    H2O cluster version age:    14 days, 4 hours and 1 minute  
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_Charles_huu844 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   21.31 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    8 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  8 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    R Version:                  R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) 

[1] 0
[1] "//bigsur/sm/Trending/model.csv"
        Date Symbol BuyIndex SellIndex BoxRatio  Thrust Acceleration Velocity nPosVelo
1   4/5/2017 GBX         132       199   77.724 49.7190     107.5811   2.9236       59
2   1/5/2017 RH          216       259    4.838  4.8380     137.0574   0.3381       14
3  9/28/2016 DDS         149       444    0.150  0.4860      99.1360   0.1081       59
4 11/25/2016 JKS         132       186    0.932  0.8686      38.9931   0.6057       59
5 12/12/2016 JNUG        132       177    0.582  0.3242      87.1144   1.1274       18
6   3/7/2017 LPL         134       180    8.954  8.9540      34.1691   0.4778       59
  OnBalRun vwapGain    Gain Altitude
1  12.6378  90.0656 -0.1659       no
2   1.5157   0.9495 -0.6496       no
3   0.5476   2.2887  4.1439      yes
4   3.2719   3.8235  0.5051       no
5   2.5006  12.0472 -0.8942       no
6   2.9935   1.1234 -0.1617       no
   Thrust Velocity OnBalRun vwapGain Altitude
1 49.7190   2.9236  12.6378  90.0656       no
2  4.8380   0.3381   1.5157   0.9495       no
3  0.4860   0.1081   0.5476   2.2887      yes
4  0.8686   0.6057   3.2719   3.8235       no
5  0.3242   1.1274   2.5006  12.0472       no
6  8.9540   0.4778   2.9935   1.1234       no
     Thrust Velocity OnBalRun vwapGain Altitude
4427 0.9370   0.3176   1.2786   2.3151       no
3079 2.2060   0.9261   1.1257   1.2506       no
3952 0.0702   0.4430   1.1485   0.9928       no
7765 1.1596   1.1067   6.2563   2.1164      yes
1682 0.6708   0.4519   1.3848   2.1808       no
5145 4.5600   0.3462   1.7386   0.7722       no
[1] "train----------------------------------------"
  Thrust Velocity OnBalRun vwapGain Altitude
1 2.2060   0.9261   1.1257   1.2506       no
2 0.6708   0.4519   1.3848   2.1808       no
3 4.5600   0.3462   1.7386   0.7722       no
4 3.6930   3.2778  11.4092  49.3335       no
5 0.9980   0.4035   1.6667   1.1264       no
6 0.2016   0.5627   2.4101   1.2642       no
  Thrust Velocity OnBalRun vwapGain Altitude
1 2.2060   0.9261   1.1257   1.2506       no
2 0.6708   0.4519   1.3848   2.1808       no
3 4.5600   0.3462   1.7386   0.7722       no
4 3.6930   3.2778  11.4092  49.3335       no
5 0.9980   0.4035   1.6667   1.1264       no
6 0.2016   0.5627   2.4101   1.2642       no

[5548 rows x 5 columns] 
[1] "valid----------------------------------------"
  Thrust Velocity OnBalRun vwapGain Altitude
1 0.9370   0.3176   1.2786   2.3151       no
2 0.0702   0.4430   1.1485   0.9928       no
3 1.0230   0.3119   3.0922   0.8788       no
4 6.4100   0.9966   5.3490   2.9436      yes
5 6.9620   0.7004   3.5810   4.8905       no
6 1.6800   1.4518   5.1933   1.7955       no

[1875 rows x 5 columns] 
[1] "test-----------------------------------------"
  Thrust Velocity OnBalRun vwapGain Altitude
1 1.1596   1.1067   6.2563   2.1164      yes
2 4.7010   0.5369   1.1266   7.5566       no
3 1.7110   0.9247   3.5819   3.0598       no
4 1.4620   0.3315   4.3097   0.4129       no
5 0.5610   0.4494   1.8738   1.3942       no
6 6.7255   1.7309   5.6268   4.4937      yes

[1823 rows x 5 columns] 


1. Summary of train dataset------------------------------------------------------
 Thrust               Velocity          OnBalRun           vwapGain           Altitude  
 Min.   :   -1.4845   Min.   :-0.1241   Min.   : -0.5299   Min.   : -4.7648    no :4875 
 1st Qu.:    0.3984   1st Qu.: 0.3281   1st Qu.:  1.1468   1st Qu.:  0.8684    yes: 671 
 Median :    1.0425   Median : 0.3815   Median :  1.6439   Median :  1.9954       :   2 
 Mean   :   12.1332   Mean   : 0.5913   Mean   :  2.5911   Mean   :  4.8876             
 3rd Qu.:    1.9723   3rd Qu.: 0.5716   3rd Qu.:  2.6507   3rd Qu.:  4.7500             
 Max.   :41279.8960   Max.   :29.4449   Max.   :154.5988   Max.   :314.7143             
 NA's   :2            NA's   :2         NA's   :2          NA's   :2                    


2. Grid Search on valid data ----------------------------------------------------


3. Summary of grid_model---------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 412 Precondition Failed (url = http://localhost:54321/99/Grids/mygrid?sort_by=auc&decreasing=TRUE)

water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException
 [1] "water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument for sort_by specified. Must be one of: [r2, mean_per_class_accuracy, max_per_class_error, err, total_rows, rmse, accuracy, err_count, logloss, mse, mean_per_class_error]"
 [2] "    hex.schemas.GridSchemaV99.fillFromImpl(GridSchemaV99.java:114)"                                                                                                                                                                      
 [3] "    water.api.GridsHandler.fetch(GridsHandler.java:41)"                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [4] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                                                                                                                                                                         
 [5] "    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"                                                                                                                                                       
 [6] "    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"                                                                                                                                               
 [7] "    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"                                                                                                                                                                                    
 [8] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:61)"                                                                                                                                                                                           
 [9] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:436)"                                                                                                                                                                               
[10] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:285)"                                                                                                                                                                           
[11] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGet(RequestServer.java:220)"                                                                                                                                                                               
[12] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)"                                                                                                                                                                        
[13] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                                                                                                                                                                        
[14] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"                                                                                                                                                              
[15] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)"                                                                                                                                                          
[16] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)"                                                                                                                                                  
[17] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)"                                                                                                                                                           
[18] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)"                                                                                                                                                   
[19] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)"                                                                                                                                                       
[20] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                                                                                                                                               
[21] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                                                                                                                                                     
[22] "    water.JettyHTTPD$LoginHandler.handle(JettyHTTPD.java:417)"                                                                                                                                                                           
[23] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                                                                                                                                               
[24] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                                                                                                                                                     
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)"                                                                                                                                                                             
[26] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)"                                                                                                                                      
[27] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)"                                                                                                                                       
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)"                                                                                                                                     
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)"                                                                                                                     
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)"                                                                                                                                                                    
[31] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)"                                                                                                                                                               
[32] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)"                                                                                                                                              
[33] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)"                                                                                                                                        
[34] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"                                                                                                                                                    
[35] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"                                                                                                                                                     
[36] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)"                                                                                                                                                                                               



4. Performance of best_model-----------------------------------------------------


6. Performance valid dataset-----------------------------------------------------


7. Performance on test dataset---------------------------------------------------
Called from: sprintf(...)
[1] "Elapsed time: 85.98 minutes"
```

Please help.

Charles

Comment: Please show the failing code. Judging by the error message I can only guess that you are creating a model that is not binomial, in such a case you cannot use `auc` in `sort_by` and need to use a different metric (one from the list shown in the error message).

Comment: I have edited to show my complete R script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve) is a metric for classification, you're creating a ~regression~ model from what I see therefore you cannot use `auc` in `grid = h2o.getGrid("mygrid", sort_by="auc", decreasing=TRUE)`. Instead use, as the error message suggests, one of the following metrics: `r2, mean_per_class_accuracy, max_per_class_error, err, total_rows, rmse, accuracy, err_count, logloss, mse, mean_per_class_error`.

Comment: Note: If your response column is encoded as 0/1 or any other two-valued numeric representaion, but you intended to do binary classification, then you need to convert the response column to a "factor" by using the `as.factor()` function.  Otherwise, H2O will perform regression and AUC won't be accessible as a performance metric.

Comment: It's interesting that I used this exact script about two months ago, and it work o.k.

Comment: What I object to is that you guys change the API, but you do not change the hundreds of web pages that still show a use of the old API. Even your own documentation is in error.

Comment: @CBrauer could you link to the pages/docs that have incorrect examples?

Comment: You are asking me to do your work for you.  My fee is $100.00/web-page that is in error. Are you willing to hire me for this job?

Comment: @CBrauer first of all I don't think we changed the API recently, I'm a bit skeptical about this script working two months ago. Secondly I went through the documentation for the version you're using and haven't found a single example that wouldn't be working. We're trying to be helpful here (on SO) and no one is paying us to answer questions on this site. No reason to be grumpy.

Comment: Oh, Oh.  Now my feelings are hurt.  In the spirit of trying to win you guys over, let me offer a web page that illustrates the problem.  Please go to: http://ethen8181.github.io/machine-learning/h2o/h2o_deep_learning/h2o_deep_learning.html.  In this web page, "classification" is mentioned 5 times, and "regression" is mentioned 0 times.  A reader of the web page can rightfully conclude that this code does classification.

Comment: In my original post I was trying to do binomial classification with a categorical response variable ("yes"/"no") and no use of "as.factor"... just like the web site.  I have a sink log and a R Script that ran o.k., using the h2o server version 3.10.0.10. I can send it to you if you want. This was back in January.  That said, let me say that the problem is not that the h20 team is changing the API. That's progress.  The problem is that there are many web pages that mention the "old way".

Comment: Back in January, my script ran, and today it didn't.  However, the author of the web page I just mentioned has not upgraded his site to show the improved API.  He is now a villain, and the h2o team is innocent.  There are no Web Police that force the removal of web pages that now give bad information.  I hope you can now understand why I am "grumpy".

Comment: @CBrauer that is not an official H2O documentation, just something some person (university student?) wrote. We have no influence on such websites. You can find such sources for most frameworks. Official docs are here http://docs.h2o.ai/